# Execute the resulted column from the select query

Tags: plsql

```
Select 'Select * from table2' A from Table1
```

The result is A. After this I want to run the A column. It should show the table2 result. I have to write in PlSQL .

Comment: Hint: you need dynamic sql - e.g. `execute immediate` - in order to run the query, once you've retrieved it into a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "it should show the table2 result"?  Do you mean you want to run a query like your example in a SQL client and display the results on the screen?  Or do you want to process the results in PL/SQL?  My open source program [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4) can help with the former requirement, but the later requirement is more common.  Dynamic code questions are difficult, and it would help to add more context to the question.